# How to get Error Description when Handling it at Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: error-handling, pdi, pentaho-spoon

How to get the description of exception when you handling an error, for example if the data type of a field is incompatible PDI throws you offending row by any reason. And so how to get the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the description you can catch using the field *Error descriptions fieldname*, and set some name, that will be attached to the flow.

[image: Set the error handling]

[image: Set the error descriptions]